# Can't install locationd snap app

Tags: 18.04, dell, snap, geolocation

I want to install locationd service on Ubuntu 18.04 (Device: Dell Edge Gateway 3001) . But I got error.

```
snap install locationd --channel edge

error: snap "locationd" not found
```

Is this app or package name outdated ?

https://locationd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli.html
https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/stacks/location/location-service/docs/installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

locationd is outdated and removed from the Snap Store.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy-hwe-snaps/+bug/1842435

**Update**

Now you can use [gpsd](https://gpsd.gitlab.io/gpsd/index.html#mailing-lists) instead of locationd.